# List index out of range when writing to file

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, csv, indexing

I am trying to parse a CSV files to get three specific columns of data. The file is very large (135MB). I have put the necessary data in a list in the format

```
vals = [[data1,data2],[data1,data2],...]].
```

Here is the function I am using to write to a separate CSV:

```
def write_file(run_name,input_name,start_time,dt,vals):
    with open(run_name,'w') as f:
        f.write("Time,%s,%s\n" % (input_name[0],input_name[1]))
        f.write("%.6f,%s,%s\n" % (start_time,str(float(vals[0][0])),str(float(vals[0][1]))))
        nextTime = start_time + dt
        for line in vals:
            f.write("%.6f,%s,%s\n" % (nextTime,str(float(line[0])),str(float(line[1]))))
            nextTime = nextTime + dt

    print("Done writing")
```

Where run_name is the new CSV name, input_name is the channel name (data1, data2), start time is in seconds, dt is the time delta between data points, and vals is the list of values. For some reason whenever I run this code, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "tdmsParse.py", line 59, in write_file
       f.write("%.6f,%s,%s\n" % (nextTime,str(float(line[0])),str(float(line[1]))))

IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is still the case when I replace line 59 with something like:

```
def write_file(run_name,input_name,start_time,dt,vals):
    with open(run_name,'w') as f:
        f.write("Time,%s,%s\n" % (input_name[0],input_name[1]))
        f.write("%.6f,%s,%s\n" % (start_time,str(float(vals[0][0])),str(float(vals[0][1]))))
        nextTime = start_time + dt
        for i in range(1,len(vals)):
            f.write("%.6f,%s,%s\n" % (nextTime,str(float(vals[i][0])),str(float(vals[i][1]))))
            nextTime = nextTime + dt

    print("Done writing")
```

The length of vals is 5550000. The function works well for the first 437294 data points but the says its out of range. Both of the above functions stop writing at a file size of exactly 16,536 KB each time. I am not sure what exactly is going on here. Perhaps there is a problem with some sort of memory issue that I don't see. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: put a `print vals` line before the loop and a `print i` in the loop. vals may be the wrong shape -i..e maybe an extra nested list.

Comment: Noticed that there are a couple of inconsistencies in your code. For example, `input` in line 3 of the function is not defined. Similarly, `startTime` in the function is not defined. So you may have been using some global variables without aware it. Try to fix those problems and try again. At least it runs on my computer with my own dummy inputs with `vals` in the specified size.

Comment: I messed around with the arguments for readability, I will edit

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution (can not comment), but try catching the IndexError and printing the content of `vals[line]`. How is `vals` created? Is `[data1, data2]` guaranteed throughout `vals`?

Comment: I guess `vals` could be causing the problem. Try to create `numpy` array `vals = np.array(vals)` without changing the rest of the code and see if that helps.

Comment: This was a great idea, solved the issue. I was creating the list with a regular expression and there was a problem at that line such that it stopped saving the second datapoint in the list. Really appreciate it!